# Blazor update list in child component when parent event is fired

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I try to update a list in my childcomponent when an event is triggered in the parent component. The code looks like this:

Parent:

```
  @if (workflows == null)
            {
                <Loader />
            }
            else
            {
                @foreach (var item in workflows)
                {
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>
                            @item.Descr
                        </legend>

                        <table class="table table-slim">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Beskrivning</th>
                                    <th>Plats</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <WoTemplateRow Id="@item.WorkFlowItemId" @ref="woTemplateRow" />
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table table-slim">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control--slim" placeholder="+ Skapa ny arbetsorder" @bind-value="@Descr" @onblur="(() => SaveNewRow(item.WorkFlowItemId))" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Parent code behind:

```
 protected async Task SaveNewRow(int id)
        {
            newTemplate.Descr = Descr;
            newTemplate.WorkFlowId = id;

            await _repoTemplate.Create(EndPoints.TvWorkOrderEndpoint + $"CreateTemplate", newTemplate);
            await OnNewRow.InvokeAsync();
            Descr = "";
            newTemplate = new();
            await woTemplateRow.GetTemplates();  // THis is calling the child components function
        }
```

ChildComponent code behind:

```
 protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            OrgId = await _localstorage.GetItemAsync<int>("activeOrgId");
            await GetTemplates();
            locations = await _repoLocation.Get(EndPoints.TvWorkOrderEndpoint + $"GetLocations?orgId={OrgId}");
        }
```

```
  public async Task GetTemplates()
        {
            templates = await _repoTemplate.Get(EndPoints.TvWorkOrderEndpoint + $"GetTemplateByWorkFlowId?workFlowId={Id}");
        }
```

The GetTemplates() function is called and I can see that the new item is added in dubug mode, but the new list item is not rendered until after I refresh the whole page. What have I missed?

Comment: Call StateHasChanged() at the end of the method SaveNewRow()

Comment: I did it but that didn't help!

Comment: If you can post a minimally reproducible example, it may be easier for someone from the community to pinpoint your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example